# Foreground form after button click

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter on login form and this should be(is just an approach) the page who user looks when the login has success.Now, When I click the button, I want to open an other form (that could be an other web page) like this:

[image]

So, what I want is to have in foreground this "form" (should be an upload form to load files). What I'm asking is, How do I show this  in the foreground ? How should I proceed?

Here the web page where I'm working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Private Area</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Load Book</button>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```